# JSF stay on same page when naviagtion returns null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation, growl

I have a lot of input fields where the user has to fill in some data. when he is done, he clicks on a

```
<p:commandButton widgetVar="submitButton" async="true" value="submit" action="#{bean.storeToDB}" />

public String submit(){
    //check if session is invalid:
    if(exclusiveTimeHasPassed()){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error", "Your session is not valid anymore. Please reload the page"));  
        return null; //should stay on the page without losing all data
    }
}
```

Now I check at the very beginning of storeToDB() if the "session" has "time-outed" in the meantime (each user has 10 minutes to do his inputs exlusively)

If the session has time-outed, he should get a message () (without losing all his inputs) so that the growl message can be shown.

how can I achieve the growl message to be shown then the nagivation case returns null (which reloads the page)?

Comment: What is not working here???

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use primefaces [idleMonitor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/idleMonitorEvents.jsf) component. there is an example [here](http://murygin.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/jsf-primefaces-session-timeout-handling/).
in this case, growl will be shown after 10 minitue and you can trigger any action.

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

<p:idleMonitor timeout="600000">
    <p:ajax event="idle" listener="#{idleMonitorController.idleListener}" update="messages" />
    <p:ajax event="active" listener="#{idleMonitorController.activeListener}" update="messages" />
</p:idleMonitor>
```

Answer (score 0):

`return null;` should not refresh the page, but if it does for you, you can do a workaround as:

- Modify your method to void
- if you still want to navigate somewhere else, use this code:

  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, outCome);

But. If the user's session is expired there is no way to update the current view, you will have a newly created view.